# How to fix RDC connection over VPN that is no longer working after network change?

Tags: remote-desktop

I VPN into my work Windows PC (Win7) and used to use MS RDC to access it, but a little while ago a network move at work led to RDC no longer working.

The RDP connection via CoRD still works fine. On attempting to connect with Microsoft RDC 2.1 or 2.0.1, I get 2 error dialogs now. The first complains "The certificate is not from a trusted certification authority", whilst the second says that "The remote computer is not allowing connections from the Mac". Eeven though I have set the remote computer in question up to allow RDP, as evidenced by my ability to access it via CoRD.

I can still access other PCs on the same work network using RDC, just not the one I want to use. I'd prefer to use RDC over CoRD simply because it is faster on my 10.6.8 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had something similar happen to me once. What I did was to go into the Preferences for RDC, and in the `Login` tab, remove the value for the `Domain` parameter. That did the trick for me.

Comment: That wasn't quite it, but it gave me enough of a clue to find the solution. Turns out I just needed to change Remote Computer Authentication in the Security prefs pane to 'Always connect, even if authentication fails' and I'm able to connect again. Dunno why I never thought to have a rummage round the prefs dialog!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in my case, RDC password was stored in the keychain on Mac. I deleted the keychain entries, closed out RDC completely (Apple --> Quit) and restarted it. This time it prompted me for a password (and saved it correctly in keychain once again) and logged me in.

"Automatically reconnect" is a feature which you do not want to disable generally.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem too. In Preferences, Login, I had checkbox "Automatically reconnect" ticked, and it tried to connect with wrong credentials.

Either remove tick, or make sure you have the right username and password.